# Send xml/json string format via bluetooth from PC(C#) to android device

Tags: c#, android, xml, json, bluetooth

I would like to know what is the best way to send string (in XML/json format) via Bluetooth from the PC as server to the Client as android device.

For now I'm succeed to send and receive data between the PC and the device.

I know that I can do it "manually" by sending string after string and decode it in the client side.

I would like to know if there is a way to send for example XmlDocument, receive it in the client and decode it with a built-in decoder in java?

Thanks for help.